# How to update Checkbox value in dataGridView?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have a SQL Server database that contains a `bit` column and whenever a checkbox is clicked I want to update the bit column with the current value.

In my C# program I create an event when click on dataGridView to update data

```
TXT_COURSE_ID.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
TXT_COURSE_name.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
TXT_COURSE_TERM.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();

// HERE IS THE PROBLEM: 
CHECK_LAB.CheckState = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to look at the type of CheckState property and what you trying to set it to. [CheckState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkstate(v=vs.110).aspx) enum is not the same as string.

You should do something like this:

```
CHECK_LAB.Checked = bool.Parse(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH .. SUCCESSFULLY DONE :)